# Como reemplazar un alert?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy aprendiendo programacion y para reforzar ciclos en JS (if - else if), quise construir un diccionario de terminos de programacion para principiantes. el codigo como tal no me arroja ningun error sin embargo despues de la condicion coloque un alert para que saque la definicion de la palabra, pero el alert no es recomendable por buenas practicas asi que he intentado creando un container para que pinte la respuesta pero cuando se escribe una segunda palabra me saca esa definicion y la de la palabra anterior, tambien intente con un modal pero tampoco pude. Puede alguien por favor ayudarme como hacer para que muestre la definicion sin un alert?

Codigo HTML

```
<body>
    <br>
    <br>
    <!-- form section -->
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>
        <p>Top Programming Terms and Definitions for Beginners</p>
        <form>
            <input type="text"  placeholder="Type any word..." class="text" id="text" spellcheck="false">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" id="btn-ventana" onclick="buscar()">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div> <!-- End Form section -->
</body>
</html>
```

Codigo JS

```
if ((text == "algorithm".toLocaleLowerCase()) || (text == "ALGORITHM".toLocaleUpperCase())) {
        alert("An algorithm is a set of instructions or rules designed to solve a definite problem. The problem can be simple like adding two numbers or a complex one, such as converting a video file from one format to another.");   
    }else if ((text == "program".toLocaleLowerCase()) || (text == "PROGRAM".toLocaleUpperCase())){
        alert("A computer program is termed as an organized collection of instructions, which when executed perform a specific task or function. A program is processed by the central processing unit (CPU) of the computer before it is executed. An example of a program is Microsoft Word, which is a word processing application that enables users to create and edit documents. The browsers that we use are also programs created to help us browse the internet.");
```

Gracias a todos por su ayuda!

Comment: ok. Vamos por parte. Si tu diccionario es extenso, hay que crear un `array`. Luego, se lee los items del array con `forEach` y se pinta en el DOM solo este item o uno mas despues de este. No se, creo que asi seria mucho mejo

Comment: Gracias por tu sugerencia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
 function buscar(){
    let text = document.getElementById("text").value;
      let elementHTML = ""; // lo iniciamos en vacío para que esté vacío cada vez que se presiona el botón
      elementHTML = "<div>"; // después de vaciarlo, le asignamos un div
      text = text.toLocaleLowerCase(); // lo pasamos a minúscula
    
      if(text == "algorithm"){
        elementHTML += "<h1>Algorithm</h1>";
        elementHTML += "<p>An algorithm is a set of instructions or rules designed to solve a definite problem. The problem can be simple like adding two numbers or a complex one, such as converting a video file from one format to another.</p>";
      }else if(text == "program"){
        elementHTML += "<h1>Program</h1>";
        elementHTML += "<p>A computer program is termed as an organized collection of instructions, which when executed perform a specific task or function. A program is processed by the central processing unit (CPU) of the computer before it is executed. An example of a program is Microsoft Word, which is a word processing application that enables users to create and edit documents. The browsers that we use are also programs created to help us browse the internet.</p>";  
      }
    
      elementHTML += "</div>"; // cerramos el div con el contenido
      document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = elementHTML;
    }
```

Deberías tener en el HTML un div con un ID, para luego hacerle el innerHTML, en este caso:

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

Lo qué estamos haciendo, es que cree un div por cada vez que se presione el botón que hace ejecutar la función. Cuando se ejecuta, y limpiamos el div de todo contenido existente, le preguntamos la variable qué valor tiene y en base a eso cargamos nuestro div. Si tienes una duda, házmela saber, estaré encantado de ayudarte.

Comment: Oye me funciono a la perfeccion y aprendi que es lo mejor de todo. Muchas Gracias

Comment: De nada, estamos aquí para ayudarte. Recuerda qué ese código es poco efectivo. Lo mejor sería que tengas un array de objetos (una lista) con cada definición. Para mostrarlo, nada más deberías preguntarle si el elemento qué está posicionado en el for coincide con el de text, el de la búsqueda, y ahí lo muestras. Sería mucho más eficiente y limpio que estar haciendo infinitos if.

Comment: Si es verdad, el metodo es poco practico pero si es academico asi que he aprendido gracias a ti. He estado revisando y mejor que mi metodo y el que me acabas de decir , seria utilizar la funcion FETCH y utilizar una API, no?

Comment: Sería una muy buena alternativa. Deberías encontrar una API que solucione tu problemática (que retorne palabras de programación y su significado) o en todo caso crear una (algo mucho más complejo). Si deseas seguir adelante, aquí tienes una referencia del método fetch: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API